# Entity Framework Rollback using Transaction Scope

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, transactionscope

I am trying to create a method that links multiple updates to database using Entity Framework and Transaction Scope. I want to be able to do a Rollback in case of validation error/exception. My setup is like this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try{
        SomeBusinessLogic(); 
        RepoMethod1();
        Throw random Exception here;
        RepoMethod2();
    catch(Exception ex){
        Transaction.Current.Rollback();
        scope.Dispose();
        return;
    }
}
public RepoMethod1(){
    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        DoSomeWork();
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, if exception gets thrown, Rollback doesn't happen. 
But it should, shouldn't it?!

**Edit**

So it seems my problem originated in me using CRM Dynamics through Entity Framework. This works when using with regular EF, but when using with CRM Dynamics it simply won't work. CRM Dynamics has it's own way of dealing with things.

Comment: You don't even call `Complete()`, so how do you find that `Rollback` doesn't occur? What is actually saved to the database that shouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't commit your transaction and that you mix up a TransactionScope instance with the current ambient transaction. Further you don't have to rollback the failed transaction by hand, this will be done by the transaction manager in case the commit fails. Following code should do the job:

```
SomeBusinessLogic() // do this outside of the transaction because it's not part of it

try
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        RepoMethod1();
        RepoMethod2();

        scope.Complete(); // commits the transaction

    } // end of using calls scope.Dispose()
}
catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
{
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using the try-catch because i want to tell the end user what went wrong so that the end user can repair the data or whatever. 
Also, my problem is that my business logic depends on the updates to database. For instance, I am modifying the state of an entity and depending on the new state, I am doing something else. So I can't just separate the logic from transaction. Basically, I am doing several database actions and only if every one of them is OK, I can commit them.

Comment: This problem can be resolved if your business logic saves the state before doing the transaction relevant changes. By handling the TransactionAbortedException, the business logic can be informed to restore the old state or retry the transaction or whatever.